# Changing execution speed of tests?

Tags: python, webdriver

**Updating with more context:** Selenium 1 had a command called "setSpeed." This allowed the execution of each command to be slowed down by X milliseconds. The team behind Selenium 2 (Webdriver) decided to deprecate this command and now there is no way to slow down the tests to run at speeds where it's easy to visually monitor the App during execution. I've read the developers' explanation as to why they deprecated it, as well as the suggested workarounds like using implicit_waits, but that doesn't solve the issue for me (or the other people complaining about the deprecation). That said, I was hoping to work around this by setting a global execution speed that would be applicable to either each method in unittest, or the entire suite of tests.

**Original Question:** I have different unit tests that I'd like to execute using different *delays* between commands. I know that I can keep copying and pasting `time.sleep` between the commands, but surely there is a way to just set a universal sleep that will be run before each command in the specified method?

```
 def test_x_test(self):
     driver = self.driver
     time.sleep(2)
     print("running the First selenium command such as click button")
     time.sleep(2)    
     print("running another Selenium command such as click link ")
     time.sleep(2)    
     self.driver.quit()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

Comment: Your request is too generic. Why do you need a timer? And how do you actually use it in a test? The example does not provide many insights on what you actually want, and the answers depends a lot on what you *really* want to achieve.

Comment: As far as I know, there wouldn't be a way to set a global and have it delay execution by x. The only way I can think of (which is horrible and would result in downvotes to oblivion) would be to stringify the body of the function itself, split by newlines and then use a `for` loop to iterate through each instruction, `eval` it and sleep for x. Agree with @Bakuriu - would be a bit easier with more context as this should not be the way to accomplish what you want :)

Comment: If it is selenium webdriver then call implicit_wait(). If it is not then you could mock `driver` object to introduce a delay for callable attributes or put the function into a string and transform it using ast module or you could replace function's bytecode. btw, you could use `exec` in this case if the string under your total control and it improves readability.

Comment: I updated the original question with more context. Let me know if I need to clear anything else up. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh now the answer is so obvious.

Create a helper method that controls webdriver actions and before it executes the action put in a pause:

The below is going to be pseudocode-ish as I no longer have access to a Python IDE at work

```
#passing in Webdriver instance and the command we want to execute into our helper method   
webdriverHelper(driver, command):
    #this 2 second sleep will get run each time
    time.sleep(2)
    if command == "click":
        driver.getElement.click()
    elif command== "getText":
        driver.getElement.getText()
    etc...............
```